# RouterLinkActive is not set after reloading a page

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, routerlinkactive

I am working with routing and navigation. I am using `[routerLinkActive]="['active']"`  to make a link active. It works fine when I navigate to other route.

But when current page is refreshed, 'routerLinkActive' is not working and no link is active. I need to select that link to make it active again.
Is there any way to make that link active once page is reloaded.

sample:

app-routing.ts

```
   {
    path: 'home', 
    children: [
      {path: 'product', component: ProductComponent},
      {path: 'dualList', component: DualListComponent},
      {path: 'member', component: MemberComponent},
      {path: '', component: HomeComponent}
    ]
  },
  {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent}
```

home.component.html

```
  <a [routerLink] = "['/home', 'product']" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">Product</a>
  <a [routerLink] = "['/home', 'dualList']" routerLinkActive="active">Dual List</a>
  <a style="padding-left: 20px" [routerLink] = "['/home', 'member']" routerLinkActive="active">Member</a>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add some code please!

Comment: I have edited please look into this

Comment: Wrap all these anchors inside `li` tags. And place the routerLinkActive on the individual LIs, instead of the anchors.

Comment: tried that also but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

try like this :

You can set routerLinkActiveOptions only for home page url :

```
<ul>
    <li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">
        <a routerLink="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li routerLinkActive="active">
      <a [routerLink]="['home/product']">Product</a>
    </li>
    <li routerLinkActive="active">
      <a [routerLink]="['home/dualList']">Dual List</a>
    </li>
    <li routerLinkActive="active">
      <a [routerLink]="['home/member']">Member</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Aakriti add routerLink like [routerLink]="['home/product']" and i have edited answer please check it and try like this

Answer (score 1):

Try this hope it will work,
i think you are not aware of Renderer [read this](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2):

in home.component.ts (relates with home.component.html)

```
import {Renderer} from '@angular/core';

export class homeComponent {
 userTypeSelect(event:any){
    event.preventDefault()
    this.render.setElementClass(event.target,"active",false);
  }

  constructor(private render:Renderer) {
  }
}
```

home.component.html

```
<li role="presentation" (click)="userTypeSelect($event)" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
   <a routerLink="/product">Product page</a>
</li>
```

Comment: (click)="userTypeSelect($event)" adding this to you want.

Comment: I tried but it's not working .. once the page is refreshed then home link is not active

Comment: have you add the code "(click)="userTypeSelect($event)"  for links you have?

Comment: my personal github page [here am using](https://github.com/shanthece/ang-sampl/tree/master/app/side-bar)

Comment: send your .ts and .html to shanthece@gmail.com